# Selenium Webdriver - Unticking all the chekboxes in a complicated table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having some problems currently trying to untick checkboxes in an iframe. The situation is it is currently possible to set some checkboxes to default ticked and some not. I need 1 specific checkbox ticked, so the sensible thing to do is run a loop that iterates through all the checkboxes and unchecks them all.

Here is where I am running into issues. I will post a sample of the HTML that the checkboxes are contained in. (This isn't mine so I can't edit the HTML unfortunately).

This is how the example looks in a situation where there are 3 different types of checkbox in the iframe.

```
<fieldset id="testing">
<legend>testing</legend>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="EXAMPLE">
                <table id="CHECKBOXTYPE1">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;" title="">
                                <input id="CHECKBOXTYPE1-01" type="checkbox" value="on" onclick="DOES STUFF;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;white-space:nowrap;" title="">TITLE1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td/>
                            <td id="CHECKBOXTYPE2-01" style="display:none;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:top;padding:0px;">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="vertical-align:top;" colspan="3">
                                                <select id="field" style="width:100%;">
                                                    <option value="1">STUFF1 </option>
                                                    <option value="2">STUFF2 </option>
                                                    <option value="3">STUFF3 </option>
                                                    <option value="4">STUFF4 </option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="vertical-align:bottom;padding-left:6px;" rowspan="2">
                                                <textarea id="CHECKBOXTYPE2-01-COMMENTS" cols="50" rows="2" style="margin:0px;height:50px;" type="text" onclick="DOES STUFF">Please Insert Notes...</textarea>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                                                <input type="CHECKBOXTYPE2-01-BUTTON" onclick="DOES STUFF" value="<" style="height:100%;width:32px;"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                                                <input id="CHECKBOXTYPE2-01-INPUT" type="input" readonly="" style="width:112px;"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                                                <input type="CHECKBOXTYPE2-01-BUTTON" onclick="DOES STUFF" style="width:32px;height:100%;" value=">"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>    
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="field_label">
                <table id="CHECKBOXTYPE3">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                                <input id="CHECKBOXTYPE3-01" type="checkbox" title="" onclick="DOES STUFF"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;" title="">CHECKBOX NAME</td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The code I have attempted to iterate is

```
try{
            for(int i=0; i < 30; i++){
                WebElement relCheckBoxes = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[i]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
                if(relCheckBoxes.isSelected()){
                    relCheckBoxes.click();
                }               
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.printf("didn't work");
        }
```

Obviously this is not the most optimised piece of code, but right now I'm just struggling to find something that works :\ I just want to run through the checkboxes, turn off all of them, then turn on the one that I need after.

Thank you.

Comment: So in the entire table, you have a set of checkboxes, and you want to set them all to be **unselected**? If so, are they *all* checked to begin with? After all, there will be some performance hit in physically checking each individual one if it's checked or not, so if you want work on the assumption they are all checked to begin with, it can help the performance of this a little.

Comment: This is the complication, as any user can go into the system and change whether or not a checkbox will be selected by default. So there is no way of knowing which boxes will be checked when I navigate to this iframe. This is why I need to iterate through all checkboxes, turning them all off (if they are on) and then turn on the one or two that I need.

Comment: OK, so we will do need to check at each iteration if the checkbox is selected or not. You are catching an exception, and printing out "didnt work" if it is thrown, could you please also print the exception too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to uncheck all the checkboxes use the following code. It is much efficient!

```
//Get the complex table
WebElement mainTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/fieldset/table"));

//Find all the input tags inside the mainTable and save it to a list
List<WebElement> checkBoxes = mainTable.findElements(By.tagName("input"));

//iterate through the list of checkboxes and if checked, uncheck them
for (WebElement checkbox : checkBoxes) {
    if (checkbox.isSelected()) {
        checkbox.click();
    }
}
```

I dont see any frame inside your code. If there is a frame use the below code 1st

```
//switch to the frame
driver.switchTo().frame("framename/index");
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: I forgot to address this aspect of the question in my answer. Nice solution.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much, now I just have to work out how to tick my specific checkbox at the end :p

Comment: glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here:

1) Your XPath is incorrect. You have:

```
"html/body/div[3]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[i]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"
```

Instead, it should be:

```
"html/body/div[3]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"
```

Otherwise, you're just looking for a table row with a non-numerical index 30 times!

2) XPath indices are 1-based rather than 0-based (crazy, I know). Since your loop starts with `i=0`, it starts off by trying to find the non-existent zeroth element. `findElement` throws an exception when it cannot locate an element that matches the search criterion, so the loop ends immediately. Try starting the loop with `i=1` instead.

Comment: apologies, I had put the " + i + " in my code, just copied the wrong thing. But yes, even with the second xpath still nothing is happening. I just recieve the catch print out and the checkboxes remain selected.

Comment: Ah, something else I just noticed; indices in XPaths are 1-based, not 0-based (crazy, I know). Try starting the loop at `i = 1`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thank you very much! Definitely something I need to remember.